# Not getting value in IIFE Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

Following is the program I am trying-

```
function getNumFunc() {
  var numbers = [];
  var i = 0;  
  for (; i < 10; i++) {    
    numbers[i] = function(){
      return i;
    };
  }
  return numbers;
}

var myNumArr = getNumFunc();
console.log(myNumArr[5]());
```

> Expected Output - 5

I found/read that its a case of IIFE http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

I tried, but its not working ..let me know what I am doing wrong.

I passing `i` like this but it is making my function erroneous.

Tried -

```
numbers[i] = function(j){
 return function(){
   return j;
 }();
}(i);
```

Comment: That's not an IIFE. It's an anonymous function.

Comment: @Barmar I checked the link you marked as Duplicate, and they are using jQuery in answers..I don't know how it is a duplicate of jQuery question ?

Comment: Also can you please share the link from the answer which is near to it

Comment: Only one of the answers uses jQuery. It also has a link to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example with 25 more answers.

Comment: @TechSolvr You are getting an error because you are building an array of  numbers not an array of functions. Just console log `numbers` and you will see the issue.

Comment: Your attempt at the end was almost right. Get rid of `()` after `}` on the 4th line.

Comment: @Barmar aaah Thx a lot Sir..and for the second link..which is more promising :) thx again !!!!!